# How to get the command line logs in SoapUI using groovy script?

Tags: java, api, groovy, automation, soapui

I am running an exe from SoapUI application using groovy script. Below is the code snippet which I got from the community and it works for me.

(https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source-Questions/SOAPUI-Groovy-to-run-exe-files/td-p...)

But I am not getting any updates/progress of the command line execution in SoapUI.

Can some one help me to solve this. I need to get the whole command line logs in SoapUI using groovy script

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","C:\\dummy.exe")
pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
Process p = pb.start()
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.inputStream)
char[] cbuf = new char[1024]; //read 1024 characters, increse to higher amount if necessary
isr.read(cbuf);
log.info(new String(cbuf))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this in SoapUI with a Groovy script test step:

```
def command = "cmd /c dir C:"
def proc = command.execute()
def outputStream = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
def result = outputStream.toString()
log.info result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","C:\\dummy.exe > C:\\logfile.txt")
pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
Process p = pb.start()
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.inputStream)
char[] cbuf = new char[1024]; //read 1024 characters, increse to higher amount if necessary
isr.read(cbuf);
log.info(new String(cbuf))
```

The logs will be saved in logfile.txt file.